# Custom icon color in ApplicationBar for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have used the ApplicationBar's Background and Foreground colors respectively, and can see that it changes appearance accordingly. So if I want my icons to turn up green, I just set the Foreground property. So far so good.

My question is how do I change just *one* icon, not all? Assuming I want them all standard black/white (depending on the light/dark theme setting), but one should be green. I tried playing with the png file that represents the icon, changing that to green (the colored parts of it, most of it is transparent of course), but it still shows up as white. Can it be done with an Opacity Mask? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the color of a single App Bar icon like this.

Effectively the SDK only reads the transparency (alpha) channel of your icon PNG and converts that to black or white with the required transparency.

If your phone is in light theme it will use black pixels, in dark theme white pixels.

Comment: That's what I suspected, just wanted to have someone else verify. Thanks.